# Prioritize scrolling in a div with overflow-y:scroll over the window

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm working on a mobile application using html5, css, and javascript which is using side by side scrolling and due to some problems with how -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch interacts with fixed elements inside of divs I am using

```
.scroller {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 100%;
}
```

for my css on left side scrolling and simply using the window for the right side scrolling.

When scrolling to the top or bottom of the left side or if the right side it still scrolling on mobile devices, the window will be used instead of the left side which has the scroller class.

I was wondering if there is something similar to z-index that would allow fixed elements to always be prioritized when scrolling or clicking rather than going to outer elements.

An example of this occurring in browsers would be scrolling to the bottom of the fixed element and the outer element then scrolls even though you are still scrolling inside of the fixed element.

I would like the scroll to only scroll the fixed element and not change the outer element at all without checking to see if it's at the top of bottom of the fixed element.

Here is a fiddle for how I currently have it set up:
http://jsfiddle.net/y1hjhLde/2/

Here is a fiddle for how I want the interaction to look like but there can't be an overflow-y:scroll on the right side for scrolling.
http://jsfiddle.net/y1hjhLde/3/

I would prefer the solution to be in css but if there is some way to do this in javascript that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is what you mean, but here's a Jquery approach on how to prevent the window from scrolling down if the `.scroller` div is not at the bottom of its own scroll.

```
var prevVal = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).on("scroll", function(event) {
    var elem = $(".scroller");
    if($(window).scrollTop() > prevVal) {
        if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() != elem.outerHeight()) {
            $(window).scrollTop(prevVal);
        }
    }
    prevVal = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y1hjhLde/8/

**EDIT**

Set up the condition's logic as you need. The verifications you can do are:

- `if($(window).scrollTop() > prevVal)` - means that is trying to scroll down the main window
- `if($(window).scrollTop() < prevVal)` - means that is trying to scroll up the main window
- `if(elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight())` - means that the content is scrolled to its own bottom
- `if(elem.scrollTop() == 0)` - means that the content is scrolled to its own top
- `$(window).scrollTop(prevVal);` - is the instruction for the window not to scroll

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want the window to not scroll when the .scroller div is at the top or bottom of its content. The browser doesn't have the same problems that I'm trying to fix on mobile devices but the closest to reproducing it on a browser means that I can't use the height of the .scroller div to disable scrolling in the window to solve this. I was mainly wondering if there was some way to always prioritize the events in the .scroller div and never default to the window.

Comment: Not many changes needed. Check my updated answer and put up your own logic, as you please...

Comment: Not really... scrolling is a browser default behaviour... You can only override it's behaviour through Javascript, by capturing the scroll event and threating it...

Comment: Thank you, I'll try using getBoundingClientRect on the .scroller div then capture the touch event coordinates and check to see if the rect contains the coordinates.